# $\mathbb N$ as the intersection of all inductive subsets of $\mathbb R$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I read in an undergraduate real analysis textbook that the set of the natural numbers $\mathbb N$ is defined as the intersection of all inductive subsets of $\mathbb R$.  However, I'm having trouble understanding what this means, specifically what an inductive subset of $\mathbb R$ is referring to.  Are they sets such as $\{0\}, \{0,1\}, \{0,1,2\}$, etc., are they sets such as $\{0,1,2,\ldots\}, \{0.1,1.1,2.1,\ldots\}$, etc., or are they something else entirely.  If they are one of the two possibilities I mentioned, how does finding the intersection of all sets of that type help us with anything?  Any illustration of how the intersection works would be highly appreciated.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Yes, but I still don't get how finding the intersection of all such subsets of $\mathbb R$ gives us the natural numbers.

Comment: The natural numbers are an inductive set under this definition, so the intersection of the inductive sets has to be a subset of the natural numbers.

Comment: But I don't get how this defines the natural numbers.  What's wrong with not talking about the real numbers at all and just saying that the natural numbers are defined as the inductive set that starts with 0?

Comment: Nothing in the definition of "inductive set" "starts with." An inductive set contains zero and, if it contains $x$, it contains $x+1$. The integers are an inductive set. The real numbers are an inductive set. The rational numbers are an inductive set. The natural numbers is the "smallest" inductive set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In descriptive set theory, an inductive set of real numbers (or more generally, an inductive subset of a Polish space) is one that can be defined as the least fixed point of a monotone operation definable by a positive Σ1n formula, for some natural number n, together with a real parameter. - wikipedia

You can't just say inductive sets because they are only defined on real numbers.

Inductive numbers do not include 0. They can be any set from 1, with the condition that if n is in the set, n+1 is also in the set. Since all the inductive sets include 1, they also include every other natural number.
Examples of inductive subsets- { 1,2,3,.....} , {1,1.5,2,2.5,3,3.5,....} , {1,1.1,2,2.1,3,3.1 .....} etc... All these sets have {1,2,3...} in them.

Comment: So even a set such as $\{1,2,3,\pi,4,5,...\}$ would count as an inductive set, because it fulfills all the properties of one (and extra elements don't matter)?

Comment: The Wikipedia definition is irrelevant here. The definition in use for this problem is not the Wikipedia definition, which is a very different animal.

Comment: There is also no such thing as "inductive numbers." The integers are an inductive set. The rationals are an inductive set.

Comment: @AaronHall   The inclusion of pi indicates that, there should be pi+1 as well... and pi+2, pi+3 ....  Your set will be {1,2,3,pi,4,pi+1,5,pi+2,6,pi+3....}